# maximum determinant of Vandermonde matrix with order $n$

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, determinant

Suppose that there are $n$ complex numbers $z_i$ which are all inside the unit disk, i.e.,
$$|z_i|\leq 1,\forall i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}.$$
Moreover, suppose the complex numbers are in conjugate pairs, i.e., if $z_i$ is within those $n$ numbers, $\bar{z}_i$ is too.

My question is, what is the maximum value of the following by adjusting those $n$ complex numbers?
$$\left(\text{det Vander}(z_1,\cdots,z_n)\right)^2=\Pi_{1\leq i < j\leq n} \ (z_i-z_j)^2,$$
where Vander$(\cdot)$ is the Vandermonde matrix with basic entries $\{z_1,\cdots,z_n\}$.

Moreover, does this value converge to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$? How fast does it converge?

Comment: spelled "determinant" (will delete this comment after you fix)

Comment: The product may be a complex number, where as complex numbers are not an ordered field so the maximum wouldn't make sense. $A=\left[\begin{array}{ll}1 & x+iy \\1 & x-iy\end{array}\right]$ so $\det A = -2iy$. You mean modulus of the product, right?

Comment: consider the case of your vandermonde matrix being $F$, the (not normalized) Discrete Fourier Transform, so $F^*F = n I$.  Now apply Hadamard Determinant inequality and work backwards.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The question is revised to be more precise.